# Adding TextViews separated by space

Tags: android, textview

I want to have 3 `TextViews` in a View. The `TextViews` has to be one after another horizontally separated by say 10dp margin. Suppose if one `TextView`'s content exceeds one line, the remaining content along with the remaining `TextViews` should be shifted to next line just like when using `wrap_content`.I don't want the `TextViews` to occupy equal space. It should occupy space according to its content only

Comment: What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: seperated by comma means?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I want to have an address view with 3 TextViews(one for address, one for landmark and one for area code) which will be seperated by comma. I just want the TextViews to be appended

Comment: can you post what you have

Comment: @RanjithKumar forget comma. I want to append 3 TextViews

Comment: @Jas ok.. ask clearly all are confused..

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want the children of Horizontal Linear Layout to be distributed over 2 rows  ?

Comment: Question itself confusing manner, please post question clearly.

Comment: @Jas have you try flowLayout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - LinearLayout Horizontal with wrapping children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961777/android-linearlayout-horizontal-with-wrapping-children)

Comment: @VishalHalani I want to do this simply rather than using libraries and all. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Jas see this link hope it help you... its not completely match with your requirement but i think you can get idea from this to make logic of this solution..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571553/android-make-left-textview-to-be-shorten-and-right-remain-fully-visible/20591133#20591133

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `FlowLayout`? [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout):

> Extended linear layout that wrap its content when there is no place in the current line.

Add it as dependency in Gradle as: `compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'` and declare in xml:

```
<org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
</org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout>
```

Comment: So there is no other simple way to do this other than complicating things using libraries??

Comment: @Jas AFAIK, there's no way. You can try to create your own `Custom ViewGroup`, but I think it's more complicated. Using the `FlowLayout` above, you can just add your view as normal `LinearLayout`, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a string builder with 1 text view instead of 3 text views - it'll be more straigthforward, involve less views (less expensive) and be easier to maintain

Edit: if you need to access parts of that textview later, you can store parts of your textview's text in String fields.  That way, your view hierarchy will be simple and you'll still be able to access the text particles separately

Pseudo-code exmaple:
string1 = "potatoes"; string2 = "are better than"; string3 = "cucumbers";
textview.setText(string1 + string2 + string3);

Comment: I know. That will be straightforward . But I want to fetch the data from these 3 TextViews seperately later. That's why

Comment: @Jas you can split it and get string

Comment: That would be complicated. If I use 3 TextViews, I could've simply read the text using getText() method

Answer (score 0):

Use weightSum for linearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
```

You can set the layout_weight of each TextView to 1 and the weightSum in LinearLayout to 3 to achieve this.

```
<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"/>
```

Official guide - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum

other tutorial - http://androidtuts.weebly.com/xml-layout-weightsum-weight.html

**Update:**

If you need space between 3 textviews add "Space" view. & set weight how you needed.

or use margin left or right